# using dbDriver("PostgreSQL") in R package

Tags: r, r-package, rpostgresql

I'm trying to put together a small package that makes use of R's [`PostgreSQL`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/) package. I understand that the way to use functionality from other packages is *not* to use `library()` but to import only single functions using namespacing. I'm having a hard time making this work, however.

Here's the `Imports` section of my `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Imports: DBI,
RPostgreSQL
```

When I call

```
DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
```

in a function in my package I get

```
Error: Couldn't find driver PostgreSQL. Looked in:
* global namespace
* in package called PostgreSQL
* in package called RPostgreSQL
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using

```
RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()
```

instead of

```
DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
```

works.

Comment: how do you connect to a db using an url , after `RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL() step
` ; and how do you close this opened connection?